# doAsync does not get called anymore after some time

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I use [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) to do the follwing udp networking in the background:

- Request a state of a hardware component every 5 second
- Send command when user presses a button

While everything works fine so far, the `doAsync` body does not get called after like 15 seconds anymore.

My function looks like:

```
// handler function, that calls sendRquest every 5 seconds
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        sendRequest(message)
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000)
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500)

// function that is called every 5 sec
private fun sendRequest(message: String) {
     val ip = getGlobalIP()
     doAsync {
         var run = true
         //some udp stuff
     }
}
```

When I debug, I can see that the `val ip =` line gets called, the `var run =` line does not get called after these 15 seconds.

I waited for like a minute, but the `doAsync` body does not get called anymore.

Does anybody have an idea why?

*edit: *
Here is the full `doAsync` body:

```
private fun sendRequest(relay: Relay, message: String, callback: (String, Relay) -> Unit) {
    val test = 0
    doAsync {
        var run = true
        val ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(relay.ip)
        try {
            val packet = DatagramPacket(message.toByteArray(), message.length, ipAddress, relay.port!!)
            val udpSocket = relay.socket!!
            udpSocket.send(packet)
            while (run) {
                try {
                    val newMessage = ByteArray(8000)
                    val newPacket = DatagramPacket(newMessage, newMessage.size)
                    Log.i("UDP client: ", "about to wait to receive")
                    udpSocket.receive(newPacket)
                    val response = String(newMessage, 0, newPacket.length)
                    Log.d("Received text", response)
                    uiThread {
                        callback(response, relay)
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("UDP client error", "error: ", e)
                    toast(e.message!!)
                    uiThread {
                        run = false
                    }
                    throw IOException(e)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            toast(e.message!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anko's `doAsync` runs on an internal `SchedulerService`.

The main question would be whether your `doAsync` calls end, because at some point it might have enough calls running simultaneously that android simply decides to not schedule any more threads until some of the older ones finish up.

Without seeing the full body of the `doAsync` call there would be no way to give a more specific answer.

Comment: I added the whole body in the question

Comment: Yeah, that is going to create a new thread every 5 seconds which doesnt end unless an exception happens while reading the socket. Android probably stops launching new threads after 3 iterations because you've trying to create more threads than cores all listening to the same socket.

Comment: Ok so what should I do different? I'm pretty new to udp stuff and async method calles

Comment: Without knowing what you are actually trying to do there is no way to answer that. Why are you sending a message every 5 seconds then waiting forever for any new messages?

Comment: My goal is to get the status of a (or better multiple) hardware switch(es) and show the current status in the app. I don't have much knowledge about networking stuff, so maybe I'm doing it completely wrong....

Answer (score 0):

Have field that stores the socket outside the Async block.

Run your async to start socket once, then you can just use `udpSocket.send()` to send the packets thru the socket (it's non-blocking).

Otherwise you can kill the socket after receiving one response (if you're sure that's enough) to free up the thread.